# develop for android - Phonegap or just use Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I've just recently(today...) found out about phonegap.

I went through all the FAQ's and I think it's a great solution for those who wish to build an app using things they already know like HTML and CSS instead of learning a new API

but...

if I'm trying to build something that requires more efficient work and stablity, I think i'm better off developing with eclipse and using the standard ADT and not the framework phonegap are offering.
Am I right or maybe just a bit prejudice?
I wanna be sure before I start

Comment: If you decide to go native look at Android Studio rather than eclipse

Comment: if you already have knowledge of android sdk and do not plan to develop for other platforms, yes keep doing native dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it depends of what you want to develop. Developing with phonegap can be faster and you don't have to learn java for the development, but you have to consider that mobile JavaScript capabilities are bad and the app won't work smooth(espessialy the transitions and animations). If you go Native, you will spend more time learning, but at the end you will get an app that will run faster, smoother and with best performance. In you case i would definitely go Native.